# "maximum recursion depth exceeded" while packaging py file with py2exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, py2exe

The py2exe worked quite well on the same py file several months ago. But when I tried it again today it failed by reporting a “RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded”. I got an empty “dist” folder as a result.
The Py file works normally, it just can't be packaged. I guess there is something wrong with the imported modules in the py file. But I can not figure it out exactly. Does any one know the solution?

The begining part of my py file is：

```
import xlrd
import wx
import wx.lib.filebrowsebutton as filebrowse
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math
import threading
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import solve
```

And the last several lines of the cmd window is:

```
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_hook
self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 137, in import_hook
m = self.load_tail(q, tail)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 214, in load_tail
m = self.import_module(head, mname, m)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 724, in import_module
r = Base.import_module(self,partnam,fqname,parent)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 284, in import_module
m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 730, in load_module
r = Base.load_module(self, fqname, fp, pathname, (suffix, mode, typ))
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 314, in load_module
self.scan_code(co, m)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 423, in scan_code
self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=level)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 332, in _safe_import_hook
self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 134, in import_hook
self.msg(3, "import_hook", name, caller, fromlist, level)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

D:\Python27\py2exetemp>pause
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd try to increase recursion depth limit. Insert at the beginning of your file:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

Comment: That got rid of the error for me, but not all i get is `INFO:runtime:Analyzing the code` even with `python freeze.py -v` on Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur when you have Jason path.py installed as described here: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/PathModul. The solution from this page is to

> Just rename
>
> ```
> site-packages/path.py to
>
> site-packages/jpath.py
> ```
>
> and make sure also to toggle your imports to
>
> ```
> import jpath
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It works for Pyinstaller

Create a [spec](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html) file

```
pyi-makespec options name.py
```

Modify this spec by adding to start of file

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000) # or more
```

Build the executable file

```
pyi options name.spec
```

Comment: The question is about py2exe not pyInstaller. This answer is off-topic.

Comment: @master_gibber this problem has the same decision for pyinstaller and py2exe as well. Because these two tools are substitute, I think it's better to post it here, instead of to create a new question-answer.