# maximum recursion depth exceeded - py2exe

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe

I use Python34 and py2exe 0.9.2.2 and I have the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649440/py2exe-runtimeerror-with-tweepy)
In some threads (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211840/maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-while-compiling-py-file-with-py2exe)) they also suggest adding the following code:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

but it only makes my python.exe crash.
So I tried to apply the suggestion here but it did not change the result. I must add that I am a self-learner. So my apologies beforehand if there is sth I couldn't make sense of. Thank you in advance for help

My set up file is:

```
enter code here
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

includes = []
excludes = ["six.moves.urllib.parse"]
packages = []

setup(console=['v11.py'],
    options = {"py2exe": {"includes": includes,
                      "excludes": excludes,
                      "packages": packages,
                      "dist_dir": "dist",
                      "xref": False,
                      "skip_archive": False,
                      "ascii": False,
                      "custom_boot_script": '',
                     }
          }
)
```

and my python code is too long to add here (it exceeds the character limit) but it imports pandas, numpy, matplotlib, math, ctypes, time and tkinter if that helps

Comment: I use Windows7 btw